# php Symfony PHP acelerator not found

Tags: php, windows, symfony, installation, config

I have been reading here and there and I thought I have read somewhere that for php V 5.5 the Acelerator is included inside the core of php, soy you do not have to install APC or any other thing. 
But when I am installing Symfony2.3.4 (checking config) I receive the message saying that "Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended)" can someone give me some reliable info?

Comment: @Pazi apparently there is no available version for PHP5.5, and if there is where can I get it? I've been looking for it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.5 onwards, 'OPcache' is bundled as an extension with PHP (you may need to enable it) and is probably the way to go.

For PHP 5.3/5.4 you have a number of options. OPcache is available as a separate package from PECL, though you are probably best off to just use APC.

If you're using a Debian/Ubuntu based Linux distro then you can install APC with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it was not enabled on my php.ini. now it's ok working like charm. Thx again